# How do I override this method on a Django Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to modify an existing [Django Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) setup to allow me to blog in Markdown.  Mezzanine has a "Core" model that has content as an HtmlField which is defined like so:

```
 from django.db.models import TextField


 class HtmlField(TextField):
     """
     TextField that stores HTML.
     """

     def formfield(self, **kwargs):
         """
         Apply the class to the widget that will render the field as a
         TincyMCE Editor.
         """
         formfield = super(HtmlField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
         formfield.widget.attrs["class"] = "mceEditor"
         return formfield
```

The problem comes from the  widget.attrs["class"] of mceEditor.  My thoughts were to monkey patch the Content field on the Blog object

```
class BlogPost(Displayable, Ownable, Content):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogPost, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('content').formfield = XXX
```

My problems are my python skills aren't up to the task of replacing a bound method with a lambda that calls `super`.

formfield is called by the admin when it wants to create a field for display on the admin pages, so I need to patch that to make the BlogPost widget objects NOT have the class of mceEditor (I'm trying to leave mceEditor on all the other things)

How do you craft the replacement function?  I'm pretty sure I attach it with

```
setattr(self._meta.get_field('content'), 'formfield', method_i_dont_know_how_to_write)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the used formfield in the admin's method `formfield_for_dbfield`:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super(BlogAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'content':
            field.widget = ....
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = ...
        return field
```

If you really want to do the monkey-patching, it should be something like that:

```
class BlogPost(Displayable, Ownable, Content):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogPost, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        def formfield_new(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # do here what you would like to do
            return formfield
        instancemethod = type(self._meta.get_field('content').formfield)
        self._meta.get_field('content').formfield = instancemethod(formfield_new,
                                                                   self, BlogPost)
```

Comment: Well, both ways work with a few mods:

    `if field.name == 'content':`
should be
    `if db_field.name == 'content':`

and `instancemethod` takes a minimum of 2 arguments (the second one being the field).  If you can fix those 2 things, I'll accept it as the answer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fixed it... If you want to have more information on overwriting instance methods in python: http://irrepupavel.com/documents/python/instancemethod/

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was answered several months ago, but just in case anyone else comes across it, Mezzanine now provides the ability to completely modify the WYSIWYG editor field. Take a look a the docs for it here:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#wysiwyg-editor

Comment: Thanks.  I can go undo my hack